# Is stream needs to be closed in this use case?

Tags: spring-boot

I am reading a csv file input from the client browser and code is below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file-upload", method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST}, consumes = 
       MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Set<SessionBulkUploadLine> fileUpload(@RequestBody final FileUploadInfo fileUploadInfo) {
 final CsvFileParser parser = new CsvFileParser();
 try (final ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(settings.getBytes())) {
      final Spreadsheet sheet = parser.parse(stream, true);
 }
```

Do i need to close the stream in the above??

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, you don't need to close it by explicitly calling `.close()` because it will be automatically closed after the `try catch` finish its execution. (you're using a try-catch with resources)

2) If you're **not** using a try-catch with resources then any stream should be closed after you're done using it so the garbage collector can remove it from memory. (A stream often uses a lot of resources)

```
try{
  final ByteArrayInputStream stream = ... ;
  // logic here
}catch(Exception e)
{
  // print error
}finally{
  stream.close();
}
```

Please note that the stream is initialized **INSIDE** the try block.

Comment: The code just used try { } catch(Exception e) only.....What would happen in that case? should we need to change it to try-catch with resources or close the stream explicitly

Comment: If you're using try-catch with resources there is no need to close it explicitly, like I've said above. If not, you should close your streams in the `finally` block. And there are some advantages in using try-catch with resources (you don't need to close the stream manually), but there are no big differences between these 2.

Comment: And the closing mechanism from try with resources is more secured in case that an exception is thrown in the catch / finally block.